# Is there a way to access the SOL_TCP (AKA IPPROTO_TCP) socket options (e.g. TCP_KEEPIDLE) in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I want to be able to set the TCP socket KEEPALIVE parameters (TCP_KEEPIDLE, TCP_KEEPINTVL, and TCP_KEEPCNT) but these don't appear to be available in the [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) class.  Based on the documentation of the [SocketImpl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketImpl.html) and [SocketOptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html) classes along with the bit about implementation details at the bottom of [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html), I'm led to the conclusion that the library implementers hard coded the "level" argument of [setsockopt](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) to SOL_SOCKET, which makes it impossible to access options at other levels such as SOL_TCP/[IPPROTO_TCP](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html).  Is there another Java class that I'm missing which handles these options?  If not, is there any way to get the raw file descriptor number so that I can pass it through JNI to a bit of C code that calls setsockopt directly since it doesn't seem to be available from [FileDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all non-portable Linux-specific options, that's probably why they are not available in a cross-platform language library. Most of them though have respective entries in [`proc(5)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [`sysctl(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sysctl.2.html) options.

Comment: I was hoping that they had left in something that would allow a programmer to take off the safety features and just pass the appropriate protocol and operation numbers down to the raw implementation as integers but no such luck I guess.  Thanks for pointing out that these are Linux-specific; I had thought that POSIX support for this was more complete.

Answer (score 1):

The manpage you are looking for is tcp(7).
Note that instead of SOL_TCP, it is safer to use IPPROTO_TCP

Comment: Thanks for the pointer; I've updated the question and some of the info in the body, but I don't think that this changes the final result since the KEEPALIVE values are not available in SocketOptions.  I suppose that I could try to experiment with setting raw int values when constructing from SocketOptions.  Any opinion on this approach before I go to the trouble of writing code?